# Swap Object Array Members Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, swap

I'm trying to write an interface method that takes an array of various objects and swaps two of the array elements based on the return of the object's getMeasure() method.

My question is how to swap two array elements when it is an object or how to store a temp object's values when you don't know what the object is necessarily.

Here's my code so far:

```
public static void swapMinAndMax(Measurable[] objects)
{  
    double largest = 0;
    int lgIndex = 0;
    int smIndex = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < objects.length; i++)
    {
        if(objects[i].getMeasure() > largest){
            largest = objects[i].getMeasure();
            lgIndex = i;
        }                 
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
    {
        if(objects[i].getMeasure() < largest){
            largest = objects[i].getMeasure();
            smIndex = i;
        }        
    }
    //need to swap objects[lgIndex] with objects[smIndex]
}
```

Comment: Just do it like you would with primitives. What makes you think it works differently? Note that object array elements are always references.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Measurable` variable to do the swap.

```
Measurable measurable = objects[lgIndex];
objects[lgIndex] = objects[smIndex];
objects[smIndex] = measurable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You do know what the object is, it's a `Measurable`.  Therefore:

```
//need to swap objects[lgIndex] with objects[smIndex]
Measurable temp = objects[smIndex];
objects[smIndex] = objects[lgIndex];
objects[lgIndex] = temp;
```

Comment: Actually no, I did not know that. I'm pretty new to programming.  But it makes sense and it works so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you are comparing your `smallest` to your `largest` (which isn't what you want) and you can find the smallest and largest with one loop. Finally, to `swap` store one value with a temporary reference; then replace the other value with one not stored finally set the unmodified location to the temporary. Something like,

```
public static void swapMinAndMax(Measurable[] objects) {
    int lgIndex = 0;
    int smIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < objects.length; i++) {
        if (objects[i].getMeasure() > objects[lgIndex].getMeasure()) {
            lgIndex = i;
        }
        if (objects[i].getMeasure() < objects[smIndex].getMeasure()) {
            smIndex = i;
        }
    }
    if (lgIndex != smIndex) {
        Measure t = objects[lgIndex];
        objects[lgIndex] = objects[smIndex];
        objects[smIndex] = t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a much more obvious way of doing it. (I'm still a beginner) Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are worrying about a problem that does not exist.  In Java, you can never touch an object directly; you deal only with references to objects.  In particular, your `Measurable[]` is an array of references to objects of type `Measurable`.  The objects' data are not there.  All you need to swap, therefore, are the references themselves, and for that you can safely use the same pattern as you do for primitives:

```
Measurable temp = objects[i];
objects[i] = objects[j];
objects[j] = temp;
```

But if you like one-liners and throwaway objects, then you might also do this ...

```
Collections.swap(Arrays.asList(objects), i, j);
```

... it does essentially the same thing, less efficiently.